# Python multiprocessing.Pool cannot pickle mxnet.mod.Module object

Tags: python, mxnet

here is approximately what I did：

```
import mxnet as mx
import cv2
from multiprocessing import Pool
from itertools import repeat

num_worker=4
CNNNet=[]
img = cv2.imread('../datasets/1.jpg')
sym, arg_params, aux_params = mx.model.load_checkpoint('det1', 0)
for i in range(num_worker):
    worker_net = mx.mod.Module(symbol=sym,label_names=None)
    worker_net.bind(data_shapes=[('data', (1, 3, 1000, 1000))],for_training=False)
    worker_net.set_params(arg_params,aux_params)
    CNNNet.append(worker_net)
pool = Pool(num_worker)
threshold = 0.6
res = pool.map(do_work_warpper,zip(repeat(img),CNNNet[:num_worker],repeat(threshold)))
```

and the `do_work_warpper()` function is:

```
def do_work_warpper(args):
    return do_work(*args)
def do_work(img,net,threshold):
    #do image predict job here
    return res
```

I am puzzled by the question that when using `multiprocessing.Pool` with the `mx.mod.Module` object, I get the error in python3.6:

```
TypeError: can't pickle module objects
```

or in python2.7:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'module'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.module failed
```

any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you're getting this exception is because `multiprocessing` needs to be able to [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/pickle.html) the variables you pass to your workers in order to pass them between various processes it spawns.

The error:

```
TypeError: can't pickle module objects
```

Suggests that one of the variables you're passing to your `Pool` contains a module (or a class that has a module as an attribute).

To demonstrate the issue, have a look at these two classes:

```
import os

class Pickable: 
    a = 1

class UnPickable:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mod = os
```

If you try to pickle instances of these two classes, you'll get:

```
In [11]: pickle.dumps(Pickable())
Out[11]: b'\x80\x03c__main__\nPickable\nq\x00)\x81q\x01.'

In [10]: pickle.dumps(UnPickable())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-7d4d725a1c6d> in <module>()
----> 1 pickle.dumps(UnPickable())

TypeError: can't pickle module objects
```

That being said - either you create your own class that mimicks the functionality of `mx.mod.Module`, but is serializable - OR (better solution in my opinion) use simple (https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) python-builtin types to pass variables into workers of your `Pool` and construct `mx.mod.Module` instances inside them on their own.

Comment: That make sense, I change mx.mod.Module to python list, and construct  on there own, and it works. Thank you!

Comment: "use simple python-builtin types to pass variables into workers of your Pool" could provide an example in your answer please?

Comment: I edited the answer to provide a link to the official documentation for pickle, which contains a list of types that can be serialized using pickle.